# Filter, Table, and Sort with dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to filter a variable by removing NA's, then table the variable, and then sort by descending. I've tried the following

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(!is.na(var)) %>% data.frame(sort(table(var),decreasing=TRUE))
```

Any idea how to get this to work?

Comment: You want to create a new table from the current table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pipe passes the result of the function call on the left as the first argument to the function on the right. Here you've tried to explicitly supply the argument to `data.frame` instead, so it will error. Instead, try this:

```
df %>%
  filter(!is.na(var)) %>%
  count(var) %>%
  arrange(desc(n))
```

Comment: Calum, any idea how to perform an operation on 'n'. Say i want to add 1 to every value in the n column.

Comment: No need to use `arrange` again. `count` comes with `sort` .`df %>%
  filter(!is.na(var)) %>%
  count(var, sort = TRUE)`

Comment: Use `summarise` for your other query. `df %>%
  filter(!is.na(var)) %>%
  group_by(var) %>%
  count(var) %>% summarise(n = n + 1) %>% arrange(desc(n))`